Sphinx autodoc - Recursion error: maximum recursion depth exceeded
I am trying update our stravalib documentatio. We use Sphinx / pydata_sphinx_theme +
the native sphinx.autodoc extension combined with  autodoc-pydantic for JSON representations.
Upon building the docs, I am consistently getting a Recursion error that I don't fully understand.
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Recursion error:
maximum recursion depth exceeded

When I write the log file out in -v (verbose) mode I see sets of warnings like this:
reading sources... [ 54%] reference/api/stravalib.client.Client.upload_activity
reading sources... [ 55%] reference/api/stravalib.model.ActivityComment
Didn't find ActivityComment.athlete in stravalib.model
Didn't find ActivityComment.activity_id in stravalib.model 

and when i run in non verbose mode using nox, i see this warning:
/mypath/stravalib/.nox/docs/lib/python3.12/site-packages/stravalib/client.py:docstring of stravalib.client.Client.authorization_url:1: WARNING: duplicate object description of stravalib.client.Client.authorization_url, other instance in reference/api/stravalib.client.Client, use :no-index: for one of them

All of these warnings are duplicated over and over for various attributes.
Here is the broken CI build associated with this pull request.
I have spent significant time trying to troubleshoot with not luck. I found a few potentially issues in our API that i tried to fix via other open pull requests.
However, if i could just understand what is going wrong / triggering the recursion issue, that might help me more than blindly trying things. Many thanks for any suggestions!

The commit that broke your build contains something bad. See history https://github.com/stravalib/stravalib/actions. I'm not clear as to why you added : recursive: as an option to autosummary. That would be my first guess to revert, and see if that fixes the issue.
